# How to play video and audio from separate URLs in UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp, media-player, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to create a video player for a UWP Desktop App. I not able to play a video and audio from different URLs. I have given my code below but I haven't given audio and video URLs. I'm using a `Xampp` local server for my case. Please Help Me.

My `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
namespace my_video_player
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        MediaPlayer video_player;
        MediaSource mediaSource_video;
        MediaSource mediaSource_audio;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            video_player = new MediaPlayer();

            Uri video_uri = new Uri("THE-URL-OF-THE-VIDEO");
            Uri audio_uri = new Uri("THE-URL-OF-THE-AUDIO");
            mediaSource_video = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(video_uri);
            mediaSource_audio = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(audio_uri);
            video_player.Source = mediaSource_video;
            video_player.Source = mediaSource_audio;
            video_player_screen.SetMediaPlayer(video_player);
        }
    }
}
```

My `MainPage.xaml`:

```
<Page
    x:Class="my_video_player.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:my_video_player"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="710" Width="1260" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <MediaPlayerElement 
            x:Name="video_player_screen" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            AreTransportControlsEnabled="True">
        </MediaPlayerElement>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: I tested your code and its working fine with sample mp4 and mp3 files available online. I found that your are setting two source to your video_player so it will take the last one only (in your case audio source). You can only set one source to Media Player. Also I set autoplay to true. I think there is problem with your XAMPP streaming.

Comment: I'm using sample video and audio `mp4` file. There is nothing wrong with my xampp server. And yeah the last source is the one being played. How do I combine two sources and play them on the media player

Comment: You can not combine two different source. All you need is to create a audio visual file or only audio or only video file.

Comment: I have a `video.mp4` file containing video only and `audio.mp4` file audio only. Is this what u meant?

Comment: No, I meant that audio and video combined in one .mp4 file. (Regular video file with audio)

Comment: I'm not allowed to combine both audio and video in one `.mp4` file. As to it will not meet my requirements.

Comment: You can take multiple media element on same screen and hide the audio playing media element. Also check this msdn thread : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2086c38-4ef4-48e9-b606-14f17b02729d/uwpc-what-is-the-best-way-to-play-multiple-sounds-at-the-same-time?forum=wpdevelop.

Comment: I had that method in mind... but it seems very doggy. Well I guess `UWP MediaSource` is not good as `HTML5 Media Source Extension` or `Android ExoPlayer`. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I combine two sources and play them on the media player.

From syntax point of view, the `Source` property  can only be set once and last valid. So you media will only play audio from `mediaSource_audio`. For your requirement, you could make two `MediaPlayer` and use [`MediaTimelineController`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer#use-mediatimelinecontroller-to-synchronize-content-across-multiple-players) to synchronize content across multiple players.

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/example_video.mkv"));
_mediaPlayerElement.SetMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);


_mediaPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer();
_mediaPlayer2.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/example_video_2.mkv"));
_mediaPlayerElement2.SetMediaPlayer(_mediaPlayer2);

_mediaTimelineController = new MediaTimelineController();

mediaPlayer.CommandManager.IsEnabled = false;
mediaPlayer.TimelineController = _mediaTimelineController;

_mediaPlayer2.CommandManager.IsEnabled = false;
_mediaPlayer2.TimelineController = _mediaTimelineController;
```

**Usage**

```
private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _mediaTimelineController.Start();
}
```

For more, please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer).