# How to play video and audio synchronously from different sources VideoLAN.LibVLC.UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, libvlcsharp

So, is it possible to play / mux two different sources (audio and video local files or possible stream on Web) and play them synchronously as one source? I don't have any real clue how to do this. If create two player is totally insane and anyway it's impossible to play them synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sync multiple streams with multiple mediaplayers with libvlc.

Comment: Yes, I know this one already. But is it possible to mux two stream together and play them out using only one media player?

Comment: You can mux them with ffmpeg and play the resulting stream in libvlcsharp, yes

Answer (score 0):

You can use media timeline controllers  if you use existing media player element of uwp to sync and play audio and video from separate file or stream have a look at this
[How to play video and audio from separate URLs in UWP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276649/how-to-play-video-and-audio-from-separate-urls-in-uwp-app)