Avoid delay between Play() and the actual playback
I'm trying to play a local media file using LibVLCSharp and to overlay a metronome sound on top of it. Here's a simplified version of the code I've been using:
private LibVLC libVlc;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

async Task Open()
{
    libVlc = new LibVLC();
    Core.Initialize();
    Media media = new(libVlc, new Uri(MEDIA_FILE_PATH));
    await media.Parse();
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
}

async Task Play()
{
    PeriodicTimer metronomeTimer = new(METRONOME_TIMER_INTERVAL);
    mediaPlayer.Play();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        PlayMetronomeSound();
        await metronomeTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync();
    }
}

This code works fine, but there is a small delay between the metronome sound and the media played by LibVLC. If I subscribe to the mediaPlayer.Playing event, I see that this event is fired about 150 ms after the mediaPlayer.Play() call. I assume, it's buffering the media during that time?
If that's the case, is there a way to pre-buffer the media in the Open() method to avoid the delay in Play()?
The only workaround I was able to find is to call mediaPlayer.Play() in the Open() method, then mediaPlayer.Pause() in the mediaPlayer.Playing event handler, and then seek to the beginning using mediaPlayer.SeekTo(TimeSpan.Zero). In this case, the second call of mediaPlayer.Play() starts the playback immediately and there are no more synchronization issues, but this feels like a hack to me.

Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276649/how-to-play-video-and-audio-from-separate-urls-in-uwp-app

Given that neither Windows nor C#/.Net are even near being real-time capable, I'd take a step back and consider using something like FFMPEG to actually mix the Click into the audio layer of the video at distinct timestamps. That should give you a) repeatable results and b) way better accuracy.

@JeremyLakeman, not related, unfortunately. That question is about UWP's MediaPlayer, not the LibVLCSharp's one.

@Fildor, not being real-time capable is fine, I'm OK with up to 50ms precision, as long as the synchronization errors don't accumulate over time. I did some testing and found that PeriodicTimer is relatively precise (less than 1ms difference over several minutes). LibVLCSharp playback precision is also below 20ms, once I get it to play in sync. Mixing the metronome audio into the media would definitely work, but unfortunately, I also need to update the UI elements at the same intervals, so I need to synchronize them with the media playback.

You could try the following custom libvlc option --start-paused (in libvlc constructor) or :start-paused as a Media.AddOption argument. This may produce the result you're after.
Also, why not call PlayMetronomeSound when the Playing event fires?

media.AddOption(":start-paused") worked, thank you! Call PlayMetronomeSound when the Playing event fires — you mean blocking the async Task Play() method and sending a signal from the mediaPlayer.Playing event handler to unblock the Play? Yes, I was planning to do that if there were no easier / more straightforward options.
